# Minimum ram we can achieve with Linux only blinking led

Tags: linux, embedded, uclinux

I heard of uclinux and Linux tiny project are very ambitious projects. It uses concept called XiP to reduce memory footprint. We can strip down binary and storage is less of a problem but connection of dram is complicated so if we want to avoid it. How small can we go in this spectrum of Linux tinyfication, in terms of memory footprint?